# Socket.io server to server (sending message to specific server)

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a specific situation. I have client (browser) which connects to server A. Server A is connected to server B and C. When client sends message to server A, I need to send message to specific server which means to one of the servers B or C, not both of them. Generally I need separated communication between servers but I have only broadcasted communication. Message from server A to another server can't be seen on all connected servers.

How can I send messages directly to one of the servers ? Here is my code snippet for servers. I just change ports for each server and connect them.

```
// Load requirements
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;//just change port for other servers
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var client = require('socket.io-client');

var socket1 = client.connect('http://localhost:8081', { reconnect: true });//connection to server B
var socket2 = client.connect('http://localhost:8082', { reconnect: true });//connection to server C

// Add a connect listener
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Client connected.');
//when server receive message from client
    socket.on('message_from_browser', function (message) {
        console.log("Message from browser broadcasted: " + message.text);
        var updated_message = {
           text: message.text,
           port: PORT  
        };

        // send message to server B
        socket1.emit('server_message', updated_message);//send message to server B
    });

    // Disconnect listener
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('Client disconnected.');
    });
});

socket1.on('connect', function () {
    socket1.on('server_message', function (message) {
        console.log('RECEIVED MESSAGE FROM ANOTHER SERVER ON PORT '+ message.port + ": " + message.text);
    });
    //change server name
    console.log('Connected to server B!');
});

socket2.on('connect', function () {
    socket2.on('server_message', function (message) {
        console.log('RECEIVED MESSAGE FROM ANOTHER SERVER ON PORT '+ message.port + ": " + message.text);
    });
    //change server name
    console.log('Connected to server C!');
});

http.listen(PORT, function (req, res) {
    console.log("Server Started on port: " + PORT);
});
```

Comment: I perhaps don't understand the question because the answer seems as simple as you send the message only to the desired server.  If you have socket.io connections to both server B and server C and an incoming message is supposed to be sent only to server B, then you get the socket for the connection to server B and you do `socket.emit()` on only that socket.  That will send the message only to that connection.  If server A initiated the connections to server B and server C, then you will already know which connection is which.

Comment: If server B and server C connected to you, then you need them to identify which one they are when they connect so you can keep track of which is which.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advices. I have tried your solution but when I create 2 sockets and then, when I send message like socket.emit('server_message', updated_message); or socket2.emit('server_message', updated_message); this doesn't work and when I tried to send message like socket.emit('server_message', updated_message);, this send message also to socket2. As you typed in second comment I have also tried track servers with socket ID but it also doesn't worked.

Comment: You will have to show the code (in your question) that you tried for sending a message to one connection because it absolutely works when it is done properly.  So, there must be something that is not proper in how you are doing it.

Comment: I have just edited my code according to your advices (If I understand properly). And I need to use this code for all servers, all I need to change is port number. Thanks for help !

Comment: You have a naming conflict with the variable name `socket`.  I've added an answer below that explains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a naming conflict with the variable name `socket`.  It is defined as both your connection to server B and as an argument in your `.on('connection', function(socket) {...})` callback.

To fix that, change this:

```
var socket = client.connect('http://localhost:8081', { reconnect: true });//connection to server B
var socket2 = client.connect('http://localhost:8082', { reconnect: true });//connection to server C
```

To this:

```
var socket1 = client.connect('http://localhost:8081', { reconnect: true });//connection to server B
var socket2 = client.connect('http://localhost:8082', { reconnect: true });//connection to server C
```

And, then refer to the server B connection as `socket1`, not `socket`.

The variable named `socket` is already defined as an argument in this so you cannot reach the outer `socket` variable when it has a conflicting name:

```
// Add a connect listener
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // socket variable name   ^^^^^^
    console.log('Client connected.');
//when server receive message from client
    socket.on('message_from_browser', function (message) {
        console.log("Message from browser broadcasted: " + message.text);
        var updated_message = {
           text: message.text,
           port: PORT  
        };

        // send message to server B
        socket1.emit('server_message', updated_message);//send message to server B
    });

    // Disconnect listener
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('Client disconnected.');
    });
});
```

And there were no listeners for incoming server messages so you need to add listeners for `socket1` and `socket2`.

```
io.on('connect', function(socket1){
    socket1.on('server_message', function (message) {
        console.log('RECEIVED MESSAGE FROM ANOTHER SERVER ON PORT '+ message.port + ": " + message.text);
    });
});

io.on('connect', function(socket2){
    socket2.on('server_message', function (message) {
        console.log('RECEIVED MESSAGE FROM ANOTHER SERVER ON PORT '+ message.port + ": " + message.text);
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried your fix but it seems that second server doesn't receive messages correctly. I have debugged it and message seem to send correctly but another server doesn't display any messages.

Comment: @mattafix19 - Once again, we can't help you with that issue unless you show us your current code for both sending and receiving messages.  Socket.io works just fine when used properly.

Comment: Sorry for that. I completely understand but my code is same but only difference is fix which you advised. And this code provided is for sending and for receiving. And again thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @mattafix19 - I'm saying that if you are properly sending the message, then the problem could very well be on the receiving end of things which you have not disclosed any code for so we cannot help with.  We are very good here on stack overflow at diagnosing problems when given code.  We are not very good when given problem descriptions without the relevant code - particularly when the operation is known to work just fine so the only issue to troubleshoot is what is wrong with the actual coded implementation.

Comment: Actual version added. Sorry for all inconvenience.

Comment: @mattafix19 - You don't show the code in server B that is supposed to receive the message.  That's where I suspect the issue is now.  Also, you don't generally want to edit your first code to show new things you've tried because that obscurs the original question you asked.  instead, you add new version of the code onto the end of your question that show new solutions you've tried.  That keeps the question and your progress through the solution clear.

Comment: I need universal code for servers(I don't know if it is possible) so code for server B is completely same but only difference is in port numbers. Nothing else. I didn't posted it here because of clarity of solution.

Comment: @mattafix19 - Well, if server B is the same code, then there is no listener on your socket.io server for an incoming `'server_message'` message .  You need a listener for that message inside your `io.on('connection', ...)` handler.  That's where it will be received.  Also, if you have serverA connecting to serverB AND serverB connecting to serverA, then you may get quite confused about which connection to send something on or which one to listen to.  You should not need to connect both ways.  A connection made form serverA to serverB can be used for messaging both ways.

Comment: OK now I have added listeners and everything works fine. Really Thank You ! Your right that I don't need create connection on both sides but I really don't know how to do that when I want to keep this code universal  and everything I must change when I want to a.g. deploy this code to new server is change port numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use one variable and configs to track others hosts, try:

Updated to fix some bugs:

```
// Load requirements
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8081;//just change port for other servers
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);
var async = require('async'); // async is optional for this example ...
var client = require('socket.io-client');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// save hosts here ...
var otherServers = {
  server1: {
    url: 'http://localhost:8082'
  },
  server2: {
    url: 'http://localhost:8083'
  },
};

// Add a connect listener
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('Client connected.');
  //when server receive message from client
  socket.on('message_from_browser', function (message) {
      console.log("Message from browser broadcasted: " + message.text);
      var updated_message = {
         text: message.text,
         port: PORT
      };

      // choice how server will receive this message ...
      // then send it
      otherServers.server1.client.broadcast.emit('server_message', updated_message);
  });

  // Disconnect listener
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log('Client disconnected.');
  });
});

async.each(otherServers, function forEachOtherServer(otherServer, next) {
  //connect to another server
  otherServer.client = client.connect(otherServer.url, { reconnect: true });
  // to something more if need in every client connection ...

  otherServer.client.on('connect', function (x) {

    otherServer.client.on('server_message', function (message) {
        console.log('RECEIVED MESSAGE FROM ANOTHER SERVER ON PORT '+ message.port + ": " + message.text);
        //socket.broadcast.emit('message_from_server', message_server);
    });
    console.log('Connected!');
  });

  next();
}, function afterConnectInAllServers(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // to something after connect in all servers ...
});

http.listen(PORT, function (req, res) {
  console.log("Server Started on port: " + PORT);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for help. Actually I can't get your code to work. I cannot establish connection between servers. And when I try to forward message from browser I get error on `otherServers.server1.client.broadcast.emit('server_message', updated_message);` line, Missing error handler on `socket`. TypeError: Cannot read property 'broadcast' of undefined

Comment: Use the console.log('otherServers'); to see all connected servers.
And i updated this example code for fix some bugs

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answers. I see that in your code you have created `async.each(otherServers, function forEachOtherServer(otherServer, next) {`. This means that you for every server in object `otherServers` make connection, isn't it ? And then on connect ...do something. Actually I have still error as in last comment. It seems that I don't have an connection created between servers. Reason why I need this is that I am working on CDN network adaptor and I need to create communication between servers in CDN network. But messages must be send directly to selected server.

Comment: Now I just debugged your code and realise that in async.each, when this code is called, async.each requires this parameters (arr, iterator, callback) but otherServers is object so there is first check where async.each check length of array and for otherServers it gives length 0 so there is no connection between servers established because it fails in first check.

Comment: May be problems in versions of node.js and async module.
Use one simple for ... you realy dont need this async module for in this example core.